# How do I make layer popup more accessibility?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I just made layer popup and I want to make it more accessibility.

This is what I tried so far

```
<p><a href="#target" class="layer">Open layer1</a></p>

<p><a href="#target2" class="layer">Open layer2</a></p>


<div id="target" class="hidden">
  layer1
 <button class="close">clos</button>
</div>


<div id="target2" class="hidden">
  layer2
 <button class="close">clos</button>
</div>



$(document).ready(function() {
  $.fn.layerOpen = function(options) {
    return this.each(function() {
      var $this  = $(this);
      var $layer = $($this.attr('href') || null);
      $this.click(function() {
        $layer.attr('tabindex',0).show().focus();
        $layer.find('.close').one('click',function () {
          $layer.hide();
          $this.focus();
        });


      });
    });
  }
  $('.layer').layerOpen();
});
```

Can any one have an idea for more accessible code ? Or any examples ?
Thank you.

Comment: why are you binding multiple click events in a each loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Avoid to bind multiple click events. Also use hash property instead of href-attribute.

I suggest you do something like this:

```
$.fn.layerInit = function(options) {
  return this.each(function() {
    var $this = $(this), hash = $this.prop('hash'), $layer;
    if (hash) {     
      $layer = $(hash).attr('tabindex', 0);
      $this.on('click.layer', function() {
        $layer.show().focus();
      });
      $layer.find('.close').on('click.layer', function() {
        $layer.hide();
        $this.focus();
      });
    }
  });
};

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.layer').layerInit();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using loops and in-lining events

I suggest you do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $.fn.layerOpen = function(options) {
      var $this  = $(this);
      var layer = null;
      $this.click(function() {
        layer = $(this).attr('href') || null;
        $(layer).attr('tabindex',0).show().focus();

      });
         $layer.find('.close').one('click',function () {
          $(layer).hide();
          $('[href="'+layer+'"]').focus();
        });
  }
  $('.layer').layerOpen();
});
```